# Prevent an addEventListener("click") firing immediately when it is created in vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js

I have a code where I `click` on a `button` and it immediately fires the `addEventListener("click")`, I want to prevent it from firing immediately.  the normal thing is that I can see the `console.log`, until the second click because when I click for the first time I add the listener and after the first time it is already listening to the click events showing console.logs

How can I prevent it?

this is my live code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="addEvent">add event body</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    addEvent() {
      document.body.addEventListener('click', this.doSomething);
    },
    doSomething() {
      console.log('click');
    },
  },
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fnxvgg?file=src%2FApp.vue

Answer (score 2):

There's a few solutions you can use ! But I believe stopPropagation() will work the best for you! I also added click.once to your addEvent function as I am assuming you would only want to call it to add the event listener!

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click.once="addEvent">add event body</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    addEvent(event) {
      event.stopPropagation()
      document.body.addEventListener('click', this.doSomething);
    },
    doSomething() {
      console.log('click');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here's the documentation for reference!
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `stop` modifier to achieve this behavior. It is the same as `event.stopPropagation()` but it is a vue way of handling events: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click.stop="addEvent">add event body</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    addEvent() {
      console.log('ADDED');
      document.body.addEventListener('click', this.doSomething);
    },
    doSomething() {
      console.log('click');
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Interactive example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-nknkm9?file=src%2FApp.vue